# Using a thread to copy image to clipboard and managing the thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that holds an image in a picture box. When you press ctrl+C it copies the image to clipboard. I use a thread to perform the actual clipboard operations.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
    {
        clipboardThread = new Thread(copy_to_clipboard);
        clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        clipboardThread.Start();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void copy_to_clipboard()
{
    if (pic_display.Image != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            clipboardStatus.Text = "Copying image to clipboard...";
            pic_display.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            var data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
            clipboardStatus.Text = "Copied successfully!";
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, if I repeatly send ctrl+C (eg: hold the keys down), a new thread would be spawned. How can I change the code so that I re-use the clipboard thread, and have it tell me whether it's currently copying data or not so that I don't try to execute another copy command while it's still working.

UPDATE

Now it works

I've changed it to use a background worker

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void copy_to_clipboard()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        clipboardStatus.Text = "Copying image to clipboard...";
        pic_display.Invoke((Action)(() => {
            if (pic_display.Image != null)
              pic_display.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); 
        }));
        if (stream.Position == 0) return; // No image was saved
        var data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
        BeginInvoke ( (Action) ( ()=> {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        }
        clipboardStatus.Text = "Copied successfully!";
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    copy_to_clipboard();
}
```

But now an exception occurs on

`Clipboard.Clear();`

saying

```
Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.
```

Comment: I'd imagine you could structure it as an infinite loop that repeatedly tried to lock a countable semaphore to block itself.  You could then decrement the semaphore from your controlling thread to cause it to run its loop once, and then block again.

Comment: How long could this possibly take?  Unless the image is huge it is almost certainly not something that should be put on a background thread.  Besides, if `pic_display` is the PictureBox, you are already breaking the rules.  You are not supposed to interact with UI controls from a background thread.

Comment: @ChrisShain since I'm converting it to png it might take a split second. Should I use a backgroundworker?

Comment: Yes, and you should use invoke when calling Image.Save.  I'll add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be invoking when accessing UI controls from a background thread:

```
private void copy_to_clipboard()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        clipboardStatus.Text = "Copying image to clipboard...";
        pic_display.Invoke((Action)()=> { 
            if (pic_display.Image != null)
              pic_display.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); 
        });
        if (stream.Position == 0) return; // No image was saved
        var data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        clipboardStatus.Text = "Copied successfully!";
    }
}
```

Then invoke that from a BackgroundWorker.  Lots of examples of that are available on the web.

Comment: I switched to `Thread` because I was getting a message saying that the thread apartment state must be STA. Though with this code, VS(2008) is saying it can't convert lambda expression to delegate since it's not a delegate type.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use BackgroundWorker because it uses a Thread Pool thread and you don't have any access to change it to STA.

Comment: See my edit for the lambda issue.  the STA issue is a red herring anyway.  You don't need it to be STA because you shouldnt be touching the UI from the background thread.  You should be invoking to the UI thread, which is STA anyway.

Comment: Strange, it seems like it should work but now I'm getting a syntax error. I tried wrapping the entire lambda function in `Action(...)` but then the Invoke method says it cannot convert void to delegate

Comment: oh, nvm it was `(Action)( ()=> { ...} );`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing the Save during the click--you should be doing it on the UI thread anyway.  You could use InvokeRequired/Invoke; but then you don't have any control over when that Save is going to take over the UI thread.  It could be a noticeable amount of time after the Click and be disconcerting to the user.  Or, it could be *after* the user changes the image.  It sucks that it will take any time away from the UI thread; but the closer to the Click the better from a usability standpoint.  In which case, maybe something like:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
    {
        if (pic_display.Image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            clipboardStatus.Text = "Copying image to clipboard...";
            pic_display.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            clipboardThread = new Thread(copy_to_clipboard);
            clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            clipboardThread.Start(stream);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void copy_to_clipboard(object state)
{
    var stream = (Stream) state;
    try
    {
        var data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) (() => clipboardStatus.Text = "Copied successfully!"));
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
object lockObj = new object();

        private void copy_to_clipboard()
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            clipboardStatus.Text = "Copying image to clipboard...";                            
                            pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                            var data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
                            Clipboard.Clear();
                            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);                            
                            clipboardStatus.Text = "Copied successfully!";
                        }
                    } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the thread as a member? Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, Thread.IsAlive will do what you want. However if you are modifying UI controls as a poster above said you should really use Invoke to make sure this happens on the UI thread.

```
protected Thread clipboardThread;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{

if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
{
    if (clipBoardThread == null)
    {
       clipboardThread = new Thread(copy_to_clipboard);
       clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       clipboardThread.IsBackGround = false;
    }
    if (!clipboardThread.IsAlive)
    {
       clipboardThread.Start();
    }
    return true;
}
return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void copy_to_clipboard()
{
if (pic_display.Image != null)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        clipboardStatus.Text = "Copying image to clipboard...";
        pic_display.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        var data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
        clipboardStatus.Text = "Copied successfully!";
    }
}
}
```